# How to retrieve an attribute value along with a runtime property value

Tags: .net, reflection, attributes

I have created a custom attribute that I am using on my class *MyClass*. I would like to be able to reflect on an instance of this class to see information from that attribute.

Let's say I have this class definition:

```
public class MyClass
{
   [Example("MyClassID")]
   public string ID;
}
```

Later in my code, I am using an instance of this class:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.ID = 18;
```

Is there a way I can get the attribute value ("MyClassID") from this instance, mc? Ideally, I'd like to be able to tie this to my property, in a way similar to this:

```
mc.ID.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExampleAttribute), false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this through reflection:

```
this.GetType().GetProperty("ID").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExampleAttribute))
```

If this is not a property (which it isn't in your example, but I wasn't sure if that was a function of the question or not), then you can use GetMember.

Comment: This is great. Is there a more strongly-typed way to get at the ID property? Compile-time support would be amazing (I know that seems like an unrealistic request given the use of reflection).

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a more strongly-typed way that I know of at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the attribute's value.  Here is an example:

```
 Type t = this.GetType();
 var id = t.GetProperty("ID");
 var attribute = id.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExampleAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
 if (attribute != null)
 {
       ExampleAttribute item = attribute as ExampleAttribute;
       //Do stuff with the attribute
 }
```